# insert multiple rows same time 

Tags: php, mysql, insert

A PHP script is generating the following table panel based on the data from a mysql DB. Each cell of the table contains a checkbox which sets the access to some 'areas'. The name of my checkboxes are following a certain rule: u[user_id]a[area_name] and I was thinking to get all the $_POST's which are set and to save them in the data base with their values.

The number of the areas are fixed, but the number of the users varies by days. The table in which I have to save the status of the table is: user_id, current_date, area1, area2, area3, area4, area5, .. area25.

The problem is that I don't know how to save this table into the database. At this moment I do an insert for each user and I think it has to better solution because this takes too much time.

```
<form name="foo" method="post" action="saveme.php" />    
<table><tr>
    <td>name</td><td>area1</td><td>area2</td><td>area3</td><td>area4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="u1a1" checked /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="13" name="u1a2" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="16" name="u1a3" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="21" name="u1a4" checked /></td>
</tr>
</table><input type="submit" value="Save" /> </form>
```

Comment: You may want to include your PHP snippet for the updates so that we know what we have to improve on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick. However, when I see fields like 'area1, area2, ... area25' - I have a tendency to think there may be a better solution. Perhaps the table should have the fields 'user_id, current_date, area_id, area' instead?

```
$users = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $matches = null;
    if (preg_match('/^u(\d+)a(\d+)$/', $key, $matches)) {
        $user_id = $matches[1];
        $area_id = $matches[2];
        if (!isset($users[$user_id))) {
            $users[$user_id] = array_fill(1, 25, 0);
        }
        $users[$user_id][$area_id] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
}
$values = array();

foreach ($users as $user_id => $areas) {
    $values[] = '(' . $user_id .', now(), '. implode(', ', $areas) .')';
}

if ($values) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO user_areas (user_id, current_date, area1, area2, area3, area4, area5, area6, area7, area8, area9, area10, area11, area12, area13, area14, area15, area16, area17, area18, area19, area20, area21, area22, area23, area24, area25) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $values);

    // execute $sql query
}
```

Comment: THE SOLUTION IS SOO BEAUTIFUL. Yo are using one insert with multiple values. TY. Can you tell me how much time did it take you to answer to my question?

Comment: answer to your question: the number of ares will not change and I always have to show this table. I don't know which is the right choice.

Comment: I think it took about 5-10 minutes, I'd guess. The $data[$user_id] is a typo. It should be $users[$user_id]. I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need mysqli multiquery. Build query dynamically. Here an example straight from PHP manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: TY. I'll test this approach too